# compare 2 sections of bundles in normal coordinate

Tags: differential-geometry

I am new to Riemannian geometry. If I have, for example, 2 vector fields $X$, $Y$ on the smooth manifold $M$ and I can write them out locally. If for every point $p \in M$, I can choose a normal coordinate around $p$ and show that $X(p)=Y(p)$, does that imply $X=Y$? The reason I am asking this is because for normal coordinate the Christoffel symbols vanish at $p$, but not necessarily at other points in the normal chart. Why and why not?

My second question is that if the first question is true, can I apply the same principle for sections of vector bundles over the manifold, since a vector field is just a smooth section of the tangent bundles.

Comment: First of all the definition of a vector field has nothing to do with Riemannian geometry, so it has literally zero to do with Christoffel symbols. The definition of $X=Y$ is that for each $p\in M$, we must have $X(p)=Y(p)$. Now the question of how you want to establish this pointwise equality is up to you; if you want to use some specific coordinate chart or some other willy-wonka approach, that’s up to you (as long as you do things correctly of course). Same remarks for sections of vector bundles.

Comment: Note that vector fields are tensors; Christoffel symbols are not.